# Maven: Project/package hierarchy

Tags: java, maven

I started working with Maven and I am not sure how to handle the package-hierarchy.

Lets say I have a project-topic "MyPrj" that has 2 programms "ProgA" and "ProgB" (both with their own main) and both use classes together (e.g. "Both").

3 packages:

- MyPrj.ProgA
- MyPrj.ProgB
- MyPrj.Both

ProgA and ProgB do have differnt dependencies!

So should I create 1 Maven project with subdirs ProgA, ProgB and Both and all dependencies in 1 POM

OR

should I create 3 Maven projects and somehow reference to Both

OR

something else?

Comment: 3 maven projects.

Comment: Would the reference to the Both-jar be a dependency to a local file (systemPath)?

Comment: it will be a dependency but not to a local file, but to a maven artifact